# Подскажите способ аутентификации

Tags: аутентификация, python, php, ruby, авторизация

У одной гос. конторы есть сайт. На этом сайте есть блог чиновника, где ему задают вопросы граждане. Как простой народ так и обыкновенные спамеры бывают шлют туда всякую ерунду. В общем стоит задача аутентифицировать личность пользователя. У меня есть на уме два варианта - это ЭЦП и SMS.
Первый вариант - долгий (нужно на верху договариваться), второй - не дешевый.

**Посоветуйте пожалуйста другие варианты если они есть.**

Comment: Не вижу в смс ничего сверх дорогого - даже при цене в 15 копеек за сообщение (http://mainsms.ru/?ref=6891), это вряд ли влетит дороже, чем тысяча рублей в месяц. Да и число мобильников намного выше, чем число аккаунтов в соц.сетях или на тех же госуслугах.

Comment: только как это устанавливает личность пользователя непонятно, разве что через силовиков, которые надавят на оператора, который данные триангуляции сдаст... *хинт - симку можно купить бес пасспорта на рынке*

Comment: Я ж указал в вопросе, что это для госконторы одной. Это просто для них в общем.

Answer (score 2):

Авторизацию через ВК прикрутите. Сейчас там регистрация аккаунта требует привязки к номеру телефона, так что разницы с SMS-регистрацией никакой, а реализовать просто.

Можно [вот этим методом](http://vk.com/dev/users.get)

```
VK.api('users.get', 
            {
                user_ids: vkVars['viewer_id'], //Передаём id пользователя, полученный от ВК, название переменной моё.
                fields: 'has_mobile, contacts',
            },
            function(data) {
                //Тут обрабатывем данные.
            });
```

запросить указан ли в профиле пользователя мобильный телефон (`data.response[0].has_mobile === 1`, если указан), и номер телефона из контактных данных, если он не скрыт приватностью (`data.response[0].mobile_phone`). Для проверки уникальности пользователя интересно первое поле, так как к одному номеру может быть привязан только один аккаунт ВК, телефон же из contacts полезен для обратной связи и может не совпадать с тем, к которому привязана страница.

Comment: В таком случае буду ли я знать номер телефона пользователя или смогу ли я его узнать при необходимости? Просто через соц. сети не доводилось аутентификацию прикручивать.

Comment: @z_coder, добавил информацию в ответ, в комментарий не влезает.

Comment: по чипу вшить или каждому тату в виде Br-кода

gem Devise

Comment: С вконтакте все понятно спасибо. У нас в Казахстане вконтакте пользует в основном молодежь. Зрелый же народ сидит в моем мире и одноклассниках. В этих соц. сетях есть доступ к телефону пользователя?

Comment: @z_coder, не могу знать, так как ни тем, ни другим даже не пользуюсь, а не только не пишу под них. Насколько я знаю, Мой Мир (А Одноклассники тоже их проект) вообще не проверяет уникальность аккаунта, по крайней мере всевозможных фейковых и спамерских акков там было до чёрта. Может, сейчас они и исправили ситуацию, вслед за ВК, я не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

email
oauth

Comment: Нужен именно такой способ, который достоверно идентифицирует личность пользователя. Вами указанные методы можно обойти создав фейковый аккаунт на почте или соц.сети.

Comment: эцп наверное тут не подойдет. попробуй через социальные сети в который аккаунты подтверждаются.

Comment: кстати, вроде бы можно еще через гос услуги попробовать.

Comment: кажется это оно http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Единая_система_идентификации_и_аутентификации